# comparing an array in a SQL query with pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using the `pg` package for accessing my PostgreSQL database and would like to send a query like this:

`const query = 'select * from myTable where myColumn in ($1)'`

I tried multiple ways to use that query string but get errors for each of them

```
const listOfString = ['string1', 'string2']
db.query(query, listOfStrings)
```

or

```
db.query(query, listOfStrings.join(','))
```

adding a single quote to the texts does not work either

how can I execute this query?

Comment: what if use `'string1, string2'` instead of `['string1', 'string2']`?

Comment: Have you tried `select 1 from myTable where myColumn = any(array)`? Checkout this doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html

Comment: that worked, thank you

Comment: @Dan you should post that as an answer, or OP could post it himself s.t. we know this question was answered

Comment: @RaulRene Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres doc for [Array Comparisons](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html).

To do array comparisons:

```
SELECT 1
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn = ANY(myArray) --  “true” if any true result is obtained
```